# Are there different ways to fire enhanced commerce Google Analytics events?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

Is it possible to change following code from:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    step: 1,
    option: 'foobar'
});
```

to:

```
ga('ec:setAction', {
    type: 'checkout',
    step: 1, 
    option: 'foobar'
});
```

I am using Magento and we use linked accounts. So I wrote a wrapper and I want avoid such code:

```
/**
 * GA Wrapper for Linked Accounts.
 *
 * @param string action
 * @param mixed mixed
 * @param obj data
 * @private
 */
var _ga = function(action, mixed, data) {

    if(typeof(mixed) == 'object' && !data) {
        ga(action, mixed);

        <?php if (strlen($helper->isLinkAccountsEnabled()) > 0):?>
        ga('<?php echo $helper->getLinkedAccountName()?>.' + action, mixed);
        <?php endif;?>
    } else if(data) {
        ga(action, mixed, data);

        <?php if (strlen($helper->isLinkAccountsEnabled()) > 0):?>
        ga('<?php echo $helper->getLinkedAccountName()?>.' + action, mixed, data);
        <?php endif;?>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setAction object needs to [know the type](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-types) before it processes the values you feed it. 'type' is [not a valid value to pass](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-data). You'll need to have your code insert a valid type into the function before it processes the values.